# NPE in FacesContextHelper under Jboss EAP 7.2

Tags: jsf, jboss

we're trying to migrate our application from Jboss Eap 6.4 to 7.2 but we're facing this issue.
When we're rendering the first view a NPE happens

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deployment.EAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.blue_webLayer-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.faces.webflow.FacesContextHelper.releaseIfNecessary(FacesContextHelper.java:64)
    at deployment.EAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.blue_webLayer-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:61)
    at deployment.EAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.blue_webLayer-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at deployment.EAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.blue_webLayer-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at deployment.EAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.blue_webLayer-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
```

It's like our app isn't able to create a faces context.
In addition I've seen some strange lines during the startup

```
10:06:34,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
....
10:07:09,505 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown JSF version 'NONE'.  Default version 'main' will be used instead.
```

We've replaced under "main" folder of Jboss' modules the api and spec JSF with the one we're using at the moment with Jboss 6.4.

We've also tried to use [multiple JSF installation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/javaserver_faces_jsf_configuration) without luck.
Any idea?

Comment: So a non-spring based simple small jsf project fails too? Did you try?

Comment: Is it ok to try a simple project like https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world-example/ ?

Comment: Better to take https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test the link you posted uses old stuff

Comment: and what if you use the default JSF that comes with the app server?

Comment: The PF test page works well but it doens't deploy on Jboss but it uses Jetty. Using the standard implementation of EAP 7.2 raises the same error :(

Comment: Use it as an example... The code... The pom.xml and creating the war directly is indeed for jetty but that should not be hard to minimize. See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info modern hello world versions

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused to an updated version of spring-faces.
Using 2.3.2.RELEASE with spring-core 3.2.18.RELEASE fixed the issue.
Now our application is running under EAP 7.2 with custom JSF impl (mojarra 2.1.13)

I'll still need to figure out how to make it work with Spring 4+ and jsf-impl 2.3 but these are another kind of problem.